# How to make automated test for iOS applications?

Tags: ios, testing

I've learned that I have to make automated tests for better quality.
But I have no experience about tests. My problem is I have no idea. I'm asking any good guidance of making test for applications.

Comment: I've recently started doing automated testing in iOS, and after surveying a couple of options I've decided to use [KIF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=kif%20github&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fkif-framework%2FKIF&ei=yipIUsGeL42TswbM94HwCA&usg=AFQjCNFus0WwHClHMyVxGCZHH1JXPbOz9A&sig2=PSPI-4xRDN3T63yUFmWKDQ&bvm=bv.53217764,d.Yms) for a brief discussion of the alternatives and some sample KIF code.. see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229460/kif-how-to-auto-run-stress-test-an-ios-app-to-find-the-cause-of-a-rare-ui-bug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Sen Testing kit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html) that ships with Xcode. I have written a shell script that will create an Xcode project template for you, that template already includes a target for the so-called “logic tests” and a sample logic test. See [Xtemplate](https://github.com/zoul/Xtemplate) on GitHub.

Comment: I decided to start with OCUnit which included by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is [google-toolbox-for-mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting).

Comment: I decided to start with OCUnit which included by default. Thanks.